# Program throws an exception when I try to create a file in Android

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to open a file and creat it if it does not exist.  My code throws an exception that says file does not exist, but I thought with the rw option, it will creat it

```
// save dATA   
try {
    RandomAccessFile f=new RandomAccessFile("ted.dat", "rw");
    f.write(cGlobals.mBoard[0], 0, cGlobals.fBoardSize* cGlobals.fBoardAmount);
    f.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: Maybe, you haven't specifed a proper path to file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are trying to do should work. But are you writing where, exactly? Try to write in the SD Card, changing your path to `"/sdcard/<yourCustomFolder>/ted.dat"`.

Also, I think you `AndroidManifest.xml` should have the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Yes, good point. I was just trying to provide a simple solution to his exception.

Comment: Hi,It still; does not work.  Is there some securty setting i must set?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but I think it should not work. Although Android's javadoc does not mention this here is what I saw in J2SE's javadoc:

```
 * @exception FileNotFoundException
 *            if the mode is <tt>"r"</tt> but the given string does not
 *            denote an existing regular file, or if the mode begins with
 *            <tt>"rw"</tt> but the given string does not denote an
 *            existing, writable regular file and a new regular file of
 *            that name cannot be created, or if some other error occurs
 *            while opening or creating the file
```

It means that if your mode includes "r" (i.e. it is "r" or "wr") the file should exist.

Comment: This answer is wrong. In the Android documentation for RandomAccessFile, there's a table of what the modes mean. For "rw", it says, "The file is opened for reading and writing. If the file does not exist, it will be created." That seems pretty clear. The exception is thrown "if the file cannot be opened or created according to mode." What's happening here is that the file cannot be created for some reason. (Does the app ask for the necessary permissions?)